# Paremeterized query string for SQL injection

Tags: sql, asp-classic

How to get paremeterized `UserName` on `"message"` value?

My code:

```
UserName = Request("UserName")

command.ActiveConnection = sqlcon 
command.CommandText = "select * from Users where UserName = ? "
command.CommandType = adCmdText
command.Parameters.Append command.CreateParameter("@UserName", adVarchar, adParamInput, 250, UserName)

set recordset = command.Execute

if recordset.EOF then
    '**ON THIS LINE** 
    message = "YOUR NAME:" + UserName
end if
```

My solution to get parameterized value:

```
message = "YOUR NAME:" + @UserName
```

Is this correct? Any ideas?

**UPDATED Solution:**

```
set param1 = command.CreateParameter("@UserName", adVarchar, adParamInput, 250, UserName)
param1.value = UserName
command.Parameters.Append param1
set recordset = command.Execute 

if not recordset.EOF then
'USER NAME VALUE'
message = "YOUR NAME:" + param1
end if
```

Can someone check updated solution?

Comment: Does anyone has any ideas? Please...

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you please try and explain better?

Comment: Hi John, I want to avoid getting 'UserName' directly to Request("UserName") on  'message' value. What I'm trying to get is a validated UserName from command.CreateParamaters which is '@UserName'..

Comment: How about `message = "YOUR NAME:" + recordset("UserName")`? But you have `if recordset.EOF then` - shouldn't that be `if not recordset.EOF then`?

Comment: @John: See updated, if thats correct, thanks!

Comment: Your update is not correct. If you want to get the value of the column UserName from your query (`select * from Users where UserName = ?`) then you can do that with `recordset("UserName")`.

Comment: @John: Okay.Thanks

Comment: @Jostine: johna is saying you should change `message = "YOUR NAME:" + param1` to `message = "YOUR NAME: " & recordset("UserName")`.